# Error in SAS SGPLOT and smoothplot

Tags: sas

I am getting following error while I am trying to plot certain data:

```
         ods graphics/ANTIALIASMAX=5200;
         proc sgplot data=want;
         series x=x y=y /smoothconnect break;
                           _____________
                           22
                           202
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ATTRID, BREAK, CLUSTERWIDTH, CURVELABEL, CURVELABELATTRS, 
              CURVELABELLOC, CURVELABELPOS, DATALABEL, DATALABELATTRS, DISCRETEOFFSET, GROUP, GROUPDISPLAY, GROUPORDER, 
              LEGENDLABEL, LINEATTRS, MARKERATTRS, MARKERS, NAME, NOMISSINGGROUP, TRANSPARENCY, URL, X2AXIS, Y2AXIS.  
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

I also tried:

```
 series x=x y=y /smoothconnect; break;
```

and

```
 series x=x y=y /smoothconnect;
```

Error remains the same, more or less.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What version of SAS are you using?  The `smoothconnect` option was added in 9.4, so if you're using 9.3 or earlier then it's not available

Comment: I am using an older version. :( any alternative for older version.

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but a simple Google search gives some options.  Why not try that!